# MVEL to validate arithmetic expression without values

Tags: java, rules, mvel

I want to verify if given arithmetic expression `(a+b)` is valid without providing inputs or values.
I tried using `ExpressionCompiler` and `MVEL.compileExpression()` as below,

```
String expression = "a+b";
ExpressionCompiler c = new ExpressionCompiler(formula,ctx );
//c.setVerifyOnly(true); // tried this but didn't help
c.compile() // this will throw exception if expression is invalid
```

This works for most of the cases like `a+b*`, but when expression is `a+b)` this is compiled as valid expression, the compiler is not complaining the extra parenthesis.

Is there any way to make MVEL to verify this a+b) kind of expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how to validate expression without providing values or inputs.
The solution is very simple, just need to enable `ParserContext.setStrictTypeEnforcement(true)`

Below is the code,

```
ParserContext ctx = new ParserContext();
ctx.setStrictTypeEnforcement(true); // this made the trick
ExpressionCompiler c = new ExpressionCompiler(formula,ctx );
c.compile();// now this throws exception for a+b) -> unqualified type in strict mode for: )
```